# CS8032 Warnings when building solution with referenced analyzer projects in VS

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-5, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

### The issue

For many weeks it worked fine, I was able to compile and test the projects. A few weeks ago, VS started displaying the following warning when building the solution or any project that is not the analyzers:

```
Warning CS8032  An instance of analyzer Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer cannot be created from D:\Dev\Repos\Azure\Platform\src\Shared\Analyzers\Platform.Shared.Analyzers\bin\Debug\net5.0\Platform.Shared.Analyzers.dll: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation
```

### Important facts

- All the libraries are using .NET 5 (tried .NET 6 preview as well, same warning).
- The project are referencing the analyzers using Directory.Build.props:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\Shared\Analyzers\Platform.Shared.Analyzers\Platform.Shared.Analyzers.csproj"
                      PrivateAssets="all"
                      ReferenceOutputAssembly="false"
                      OutputItemType="Analyzer"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

### What I tried

- VS 16.10. - **Warning**
- Updating to VS 16.11. - **Warning**
- Installing VS 17 Preview (2022) and upgrading to .NET 6. - **Warning**
- PowerShell `dotnet build` and `dotnet msbuild`. - **No warning**
- JetBrains Rider. - **No warning**
- Azure DevOps build agent. - **No warning**

### Full warning

I enabled Fusion Log to get the full log.
From the "Error List" (one is generated for each analyzer for each project referencing the analyzers project):

```
Warning CS8032  An instance of analyzer Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer cannot be created from D:\Dev\Repos\Azure\Platform\src\Shared\Analyzers\Platform.Shared.Analyzers\bin\Debug\net5.0\Platform.Shared.Analyzers.dll: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation..  Platform.Shared.Core        1   Active  System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer..ctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerFileReference.Extensions`1.GetAnalyzersForTypeNames(Assembly analyzerAssembly, IEnumerable`1 analyzerTypeNames, Boolean& reportedError)
-----
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Platform.Shared.Analyzers.Rules.StructuredMessageTemplateAnalyzer..ctor()
-----
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
-----
=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Platform.Shared.Analyzers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
===
LOG: This bind starts in LoadFrom load context.
WRN: Native image will not be probed in LoadFrom context. Native image will only be probed in default load context, like with Assembly.Load().
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\Shay\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_0bee0d9b\devenv.exe.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PublicAssemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/TestWindow/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Platform/Debugger/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Professional/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies/DataCollectors/x86/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shay/AppData/Local/Temp/VS/AnalyzerAssemblyLoader/2dfa9a6f85874e39aff972af6188cb73/5/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shay/AppData/Local/Temp/VS/AnalyzerAssemblyLoader/2dfa9a6f85874e39aff972af6188cb73/5/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shay/AppData/Local/Temp/VS/AnalyzerAssemblyLoader/2dfa9a6f85874e39aff972af6188cb73/5/System.Runtime.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Shay/AppData/Local/Temp/VS/AnalyzerAssemblyLoader/2dfa9a6f85874e39aff972af6188cb73/5/System.Runtime/System.Runtime.EXE.

-----
```

### **Workaround**

As a temporary workaround, I added the following property to the solution `Directory.Build.props`:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true'">
    <!-- Visual Studio compiler displays the CS8032 warning for unknown reason. Removing it manually to declutter the Error List -->
    <NoWarn>$(NoWarn),8032</NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Have you tried to change the SG project to use .NET standard 2.0?

Comment: @KhaledSaleh any specific reason that should matter? At the time of this post I was using C# 9 syntax and therefore had to use .NET 5. Now, I am using C# 10 and targeting .NET 6.
With .NET 6, the warning is displayed on 4-5 of the projects in the solution (regardless of the `NoWarn` property) as oppose to all the projects in .NET 5. Very odd.

Comment: It matters if your source generator is not targeting 2.0. As of now, this is still true, any SG needs to be only targeting .Net standard 2.0. I've seen this error before when my SG itself was referencing .Net 5.0. Please refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview

Comment: @KhaledSaleh Thanks for the link, I see their "tip" about the TFM. I've only tried to target both netstandard2.0 and net6.0, I will give it a try on my next availability.

Comment: @KhaledSaleh That indeed solved the problem. Thank you! Would you like to write it as an answer and get the credit for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this issue before and it happens because you use .Net 5.0 for the source generator project. Source generator' projects have to be only **.Net standard 2.0** as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview).